# How do i disable price, shipping and payment in ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I need to set up a "shopping cart" to allow users to collect URLs from my local database. All my products are free. Based on which URLs are in the users "basket" I fetch files and pack them in a tar file and send the user a URL where the tar file can be downloaded.

How can I turn off or hide price, payment and shipping in ubercart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UC Price Visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_price_visibility) Module.

> Often, you want to advertise your products without revealing the prices, and show something
>   like, "contact us for pricing." This Ubercart module allows you to show or hide product pricing per role, on a product-by-product basis. You can configure what message should be shown when the price is hidden, and which field should be replaced with this message (either the display price, sell price, or add to cart button).

Comment: Thanks Krishna, UC Price Visibility looks promising. I'll try it.